# How can I use Android Studio 1.0 without Gradle or Maven?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I just want to start a simple Android project and quickly make changes and install it on my phone using simple `right-click --> Run as an Android application`.

I could do this in Eclipse but I really like Android Studio's (i.e. IntelliJ IDEA's editor features). But because Android Studio has all the Android dependency bundled with it I decided not to install IntelliJ IDEA and rather went with Android Studio 1.0.

I am getting plethora of errors with Gradle which I am not even adding in my project while trying to start one, neither can I find a way to remove Gradle from my project. My Android Studi 1.0 installation is standard installation on Windows 7 and I can see `gradle 2.2.1` in `plugins` folder but it just doesn't work. I expected everything to work out of the box as its just a dummy app with default UI components selected from SDK while creating the project.

Is there a way to simple app building experience in Android Studio without dealing with Gradle and its dependency and set-up?

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio uses Gradle as its build engine. There is no way to use one without the other. That said, the "New Project" wizard should get you up and running quickly.

Comment: It didn't. I installed the default installer. I even tried troubleshooting after I started facing problems but nothing worked.

Comment: If you describe *in detail* what *exactly* you did and which *exact* problem occurred, then someone might be able to help out.